# Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Tags: php

I'm busy on this site, and I need to get the 'tweets' that staff members send from the database. So, I was like, okay, lets connect to the database and see what happens.This is the code (Till the execute part, after that you don't really need it.)

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '123', 'gh24hh');
$stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM tweet ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5');
$stmt->execute();
```

And this is the erro that gets thrown:

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter.php on line 5
```

Obviously line five is the execute line.

Does anybody see my mistake?

(If more code is needed, please say so, because I didn't really know what to post with the question)

Comment: Have you looked in your error logs? Maybe increase the error reporting level? Is the $connection successfully setup? Does the SQL run successfully in a mysql console?

Comment: `$stmt` is null, something went wrong on line 4

Answer (score 0):

The error is raise because the variable `$stmt` returns false.For $stmt to return something you need to correct your query

As @joe pointed out in the comment `it returns the statement object, or false if something went wrong`.It doesnt return null.

Comment: Technically incorrect: http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php - it returns the statement object, or `false` if something went wrong. It never returns `null`. It's also more useful to tell him why it's not returning the statement object ("something went wrong in the query") instead of just omitting it. You make it sound like `$stmt` is not expected to ever contain a statement object

Comment: @Joe is that enough ??..:)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '123', 'gh24hh');
$result = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM tweet ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5')
```